# Concatenating a receipt for a Forms application

Tags: c#, .net

So what I've been trying to do for quite some time now was concatenate selected radio buttons on a form into a list box so it will read out as a receipt. I declared a variable receipt as an empty string, and I was curious how I would be able to fill the receipt variable with my radio buttons that are checked. I can provide the code I have if needed, although I am unsure if it will help.

Code is provided below

```
public class Order
    {
        public string[] pizzaChoice = new
        string[] {"Plain Slice", "Medium Plain", "Large Plain", "White Slice", "Medium White", "Large White",
                  "Roar Slice", "Roar Medium", "Roar Large", "BBQ Slice", "BBQ Medium", "BBQ Large", 
                  "Cheeseburger Slice", "Cheeseburger Medium", "Cheeseburger Large", "Buffalo Slice", "Buffalo Medium", "Buffalo Large",
                  "The Works Slice", "The Works Medium", "The Works Large"};
        public decimal[] pizzaChoicePrice = new decimal[] {1.50m, 8.00m, 10.00m, 1.75m, 9.00m, 12.00m,
                                                           2.00m, 9.00m, 12.00m, 2.00m, 9.00m, 12.00m,
                                                           2.00m, 9.00m, 12.00m, 2.00m, 9.00m, 12.00m,
                                                           2.50m, 10.00m, 13.00m};
        private string pizza;
        private string drink;
        private string specialRequest;
        private decimal pizzaPrice;
        private decimal drinkPrice;

        public Order()
        {
            pizza = "";
            specialRequest = "";
            drinkPrice = 0;
            pizzaPrice = 0;
        }
        public string Pizza
        {
            get
            {
                return pizza;
            }
            set
            {
                pizza = value;
                SetPizzaPrice();
            }
        }
        public string SpecialRequests
        {
            get
            {
                return specialRequest;
            }
            set
            {
                specialRequest = value;
            }
        }
        public string Drink
        { 
            get
            {
                return drink;
            }
            set 
            {
                drink = value;
                SetDrinkPrice();
            }
        }
        public decimal PizzaPrice
        {
            get
            {
                return pizzaPrice;
            }
        }
        public decimal DrinkPrice
        {
            get
            {
                return drinkPrice;
            }
        }
        public void SetPizzaPrice()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < pizzaChoice.Length; i++)
            {
                if (pizzaChoice[i] == pizza)
                {
                    pizzaPrice = pizzaChoicePrice[i];
                }
            }
        }
        public void SetDrinkPrice()
        {
            switch (drink)
            {
                case "Small Water":
                case "Medium Water":
                case "Large Water":
                    drinkPrice = 0.00m;
                    break;
                case "Small Fountain Soda":
                case "Can of Soda":
                    drinkPrice = 0.75m;
                    break;
                case "Medium Fountain Soda":
                    drinkPrice = 1.25m;
                    break;
                case "Large Fountain Soda":
                case "Large Iced Tea/Lemonade/Juice":
                    drinkPrice = 2.00m;
                    break;
                case "20 oz Bottled Soda":
                    drinkPrice = 1.75m;
                    break;
                case "2 Liter Bottled Soda":
                    drinkPrice = 2.50m;
                    break;
                case "12 oz Iced Tea/Lemonade/Juice":
                    drinkPrice = 1.00m;
                    break;
                case "24 oz Iced Tea/Lemonade/Juice":
                    drinkPrice = 1.50m;
                    break;
            }
        }
        public decimal TotalBeforeTax()
        {
            return pizzaPrice + drinkPrice;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

Put the various things and prices that can be ordered in a seperate Menu class. This allows you to put any responsibilities concerning what can be ordered in a single spot. This will keep the class Order cleaner.

Create a method `PlaceOrder`, `CreateOrder` or `Order` on the Menu class. Have it create and return an Order. This way the Order class is just responsible for keeping track of what has been ordered.

In the user interface/form create the radiobuttons and other controls any way you like (you could even use the information in the Menu class to dynamically build the UI). In a click event of a button pass all selected items and amounts to the PlaceOrder method.

To get the Order back in some readable way add a method to the Order class `Print` and return from this method the data that has been stored in the Order object in a acceptable format. You could have the `Print` method return a single string but it could also be an array of strings.

Please post any specific questions if you are having difficulties implementing this. Try to be very specific and show us what you have tried.